# Right sidebar image in Wordpress with target URL

Tags: php, wordpress

In our WordPress theme we have defined the Taxonomy Article Category pages for our knowledgebase. Basically an overview page. One of the elements in the overview page is the sidebare image in the right part of the page.

You should be able to insert an image and insert a target URL which opens the page on click. However, it is not working exactly as it should.

Two things are not going well:

1. If you enter a URL in the backend but don't upload an image, it automatically grabs a default banner.
2. The URL is not placed correctly after the image. The image is not clickable.

See php for right part element below

```
<div class="rightPart">
            <?php
            $sidebar_image = get_field('sidebar_image');
            if($sidebar_image){
                $sidebar_image_url     = $sidebar_image['url'];
                $sidebar_image_title   = $sidebar_image['title'];
                $sidebar_image_alt     = $sidebar_image['alt'];
                $sidebar_image_caption = $sidebar_image['caption'];
            }
            $sidebar_image_link = get_field('sidebar_image_link');
            if( $sidebar_image_link ){
                $promo_link_url   = $sidebar_image_link['url'];
                $promo_link_title = $sidebar_image_link['title'];
                $promo_link_target= $sidebar_image_link['target'] ? $sidebar_image_link['target'] : '_self';
                ?>
                <a target="<?php echo $promo_link_target; ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( $promo_link_url ); ?>" title="<?php echo $promo_link_title; ?>" >
                    <?php
                    if($sidebar_image){
                        ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $sidebar_image['url']; ?>" width="<?php echo $sidebar_image['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $sidebar_image['height']; ?>" title="<?php echo $sidebar_image['title']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $sidebar_image['title']; ?>">
                        <?php
                    } ?>
                </a>
                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <?php
                if($sidebar_image){
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $sidebar_image['url']; ?>" width="<?php echo $sidebar_image['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $sidebar_image['height']; ?>" title="<?php echo $sidebar_image['title']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $sidebar_image['title']; ?>">
                    <?php
                }?>
                <?php
            } ?>
        </div>
```

I took a quick look. The Sidebar_Image_Link returned an empty string. I then looked in WordPress to see where these fields are defined.

We apparently use Advanced Custom Fields plugin for this. There, we created two field groups for this section:

1. Parent articles
2. Child articles

Both field groups have a field called: Sidebar_image_link

What occurs next. When I fill the field with a link for both parent and one child, it does return the sidebar_image_link for both articles. But when I remove the link from the child article, it returns an empty string for the parent.

How it should be is that we can enter this value specifically for both the parent and the child, independently. Something isn't going right there, but I can't put my finger on what's wrong.

Comment: _"If you enter a URL in the backend but don't upload an image, it automatically grabs a default banner."_ - and that is what is currently happening, but you don't want that; or is it what you want, but can't figure out how to implement?

Comment: _"The URL is not placed correctly after the image. The image is not clickable."_ - what do you mean by "placed after"? For the image to link somewhere, the URL needs to be in the href attribute of the link _containing_ the image (which you appear to have implemented), so what is with "after" now?

Comment: "If you enter a URL in the backend but don't upload an image, it automatically grabs a default banner." - and that is what is currently happening, but you don't want that; or is it what you want, but can't figure out how to implement? 

How it should be, is that we select an image in the backend. And that it uses that specific image. Sorry if the explanation is not that specific. Trying to bring it the best I can.

Comment: "The URL is not placed correctly after the image. The image is not clickable." - what do you mean by "placed after"? For the image to link somewhere, the URL needs to be in the href attribute of the link containing the image (which you appear to have implemented), so what is with "after" now? – 

I meant that the image should indeed linke somewhere. At this moment, when we insert a link in the backend, it does not link anywhere in the frond end unfortunately.

Comment: What have you done to try and debug this then so far? If you get the image output "naked", without being wrapped into a link at all - then obviously your `if( $sidebar_image_link )` condition wasn't fulfilled to begin with.

Comment: Well, that is the weird thing. Condition $sidebar_image_link condition is fulfilled, but I still get it out naked, without being wrapped into a link at all. 

The reason I am here, is because I am not a php expert myself and got this problem thrown at me actually. So hoped to get some help from here and learn something as well.

Comment: We can not look into your system from the outside, so you will still need to do some basic debugging yourself here. Verify what $promo_link_url contains, check what `esc_url` actually makes out of the value, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252083/discussion-between-marc-lonsain-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sidebar_image_link = get_field('sidebar_image_link');
```

This value results in a false boolean. Debug this statement to check.